# Passing Value in Struts 2 from JSP to JSP

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have the code below in a JSP page.

```
<s:url value="/user/search.jsp" >
    <s:param name="profile.gender" value="profile.gender"></s:param>
</s:url>
```

It links perfectly to /user/search.jsp and the value of profile.gender is displayed in browser's address bar (a query string). In my /user/search.jsp, how to access and display the value of the profile.gender in a textfield?

```
<s:textfield value="?"/>
```

Comment: i am not sure if the search.jsp is another page? and are you trying to call one jsp from another without using any Action class?

Comment: yes, search.jsp is another page.

Comment: I am  not sure why you are trying to do this as you are violating MVC2 basic principle.Every request from one JSP to another JSP should go through a Action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested already dont move from jsp to jsp instead go through action

```
<s:url value="myaction.action" >
    <s:param name="gender" value="profile.gender"></s:param>
</s:url>

@Result(name="success", value="/search.jsp") // If you prefer annotation or configure in xml
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
  private String gender = null;
  //getter setter here    
  public String execute(){
    return Action.SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

search.jsp

```
<s:textfield value="gender"/>
```